# Extract nested object property using string path in angular

Tags: json, angular, angular-template

Is there some way I can pass a nested path from the controller to then be used in the template?
I want the type binding in the template to pass off what is at the path of **change.Property.PropertyName**

Controller

```
private _columns = [
    { field: 'Name', title: 'Type', displayType: 'Property.PropertyName' },
    { field: 'ChangeDate', title: 'Date', displayType: 'Date' }
]
```

Template

```
<tr *ngFor="let change in changes">
    <td *ngFor="let col of _columns">
        <z-grid-cell-display [type]="change[col.displayType]" [field]="change" [context]="change[col.field]"></z-grid-cell-display>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**EDIT**
Right now as it's shown here the [type] binding is resolving to

```
change['Property.PropertyName'] which is undefined
```

Comment: can you explain yourself better I don't fully understand what do you need

Comment: I am building a table. Each row is an NgFor of an array containing objects. Foreach cell I want to access the displayType of the property which of the change object. Some of them are nested, some of them are not

Comment: @BrianMcCall Did you try `{{eval('change.' + col.displayType)}}`? *Only* if you entirely control your `change` and `_columns` data, of course, otherwise `eval` is to be prohibited. But that should work.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a recursive function like:

```
@Component({...})
export class Foo {
   transform(value: any, name: string): any {
    if (Array.isArray(value) || !(value instanceof Object) || !name) {
      return value;
    } else if (name.indexOf('.') > -1) {
      const splitName: string[] = name.split(/\.(.+)/, 2);
      return this.transform(value[splitName[0]], splitName[1]);
    } else {
      return value[name];
    }
  }
}
```

And use it in your template as follows:

```
<td *ngFor="let col of _columns">
    <z-grid-cell-display [type]="transform(change, col.displayTipe)" [field]="change" [context]="change[col.field]"></z-grid-cell-display>
</td>
```

Another approach would be to move this into a pipe

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'propertyValue'
})
export class PropertyValuePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, name: string): any {
    if (Array.isArray(value) || !(value instanceof Object) || !name) {
      return value;
    } else if (name.indexOf('.') > -1) {
      const splitName: string[] = name.split(/\.(.+)/, 2);
      return this.transform(value[splitName[0]], splitName[1]);
    } else {
      return value[name];
    }
  }
}
```

And then

```
 <td *ngFor="let col of _columns">
        <z-grid-cell-display 
         [type]="change | propertyValue: col.displayTipe" 
         [field]="change" 
         [context]="change | propertyValue: col.field">
        </z-grid-cell-display>
    </td>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I like the pipe approach better and had thought of doing that myself but I was really hoping there would be a much simpler answer :-( something like change[{{col.displayType}}].
Thanks again

Comment: Nope, not possible without doing something like change[property][propertyname]

Comment: Yes but this account of mine doesnt have enough rep to mark answer as solved. :-(

Comment: @BrianMcCall oh thats a shame. Welp, be sure to comeback at some point otherwise this question/answer will be removed by the garbage collector.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo - I'll just have to use this account ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple method for this.

```js
resolve(stringPath, baseObject): any {
return stringPath.split('.').reduce((p, q) => {
return p ? p[q] : null;
} , baseObject|| self);
  }
```

Then you can call this method

```
resolve('customer.address.line1', customerObject);
```

I hope this will helpful to fix similar problems and construct a answer for this question.